# Advice on establishing a solid career

Tags: airlines, ground-instructor, school

1.Do you feel that students who does not have the opportunity to attend the popular schools can be at a disadvantage when applying for jobs at the airlines?

***Rant***
My Thing is I would love to go to a school known for their outstanding programs and thats not to say those schools are/are not pushing great pilots but cost wise, I just don't have it and the time to save for it, is not an option.

Second question is, How does one groom themselves to become that of an airline pilot.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To get hired at the airlines now (and for the foreseeable future), you need the necessary ratings, and you need experience (hours).

When you have those, nobody cares which school you went to.

There have been times when airlines had multiple applicants for every opening, and in those days, having an "in", either from having gone to the right school or being part of the right network or knowing the right people at the airline, was tremendously helpful in distinguishing yourself from all the other candidates. That isn't the case now. If you meet all the requirements, don't have any grave red flags (i.e. DUI or other criminal history) on your resume, and don't say &$#@ too often in the interview, your chances of getting hired are very good.

Answer (score 7):

You might consider the old fashion way. Use a part 61 instructor, get your Private, Commercial/Instrument and Multiengine ratings. Then get a Flight Instructor-airplane single-engine rating (add, when you can, an instrument and mulitengine instructor rating).

Start instructing and building flight time (80-100 hours/month). Supplement that, when you can, as an Air Taxi pilot (FAR Part 135). Within 2 years you could have an Airline Transport pilot certificate and apply with the Airlines. Lots of experience, much less expensive.